# Using Moq Unable to Verify Mocked Call With Default Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

Attempting to call verify on a Mocked dependency always fails no matter how general I make the Setup.

Here is the method signature on the interface I am hoping to mock:

```
Task EnqueueAsync<T>(string factoryId, string clientId, T messageObject, string messageId = null, string messageLabel = null, bool forcePersistence = true, DateTime? scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = null, Dictionary<string, object> properties = null, double retryTime = 0);
```

Here is my Setup method:

```
mockTopic = new Mock<ITopic>();
mockTopic.Setup(m => m.EnqueueAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<DateTime?>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>(), It.IsAny<double>()))
.Callback((string factoryId, string clientId, string messageObject, string messageId, string messageLabel, bool forcePersistence, DateTime? scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc, Dictionary<string, object> properties, double retryTime) =>
{
    testProperties = properties;
    testMessageId = messageId;
});
```

Here is my call to verify:

```
mockTopic.Verify(m => m.EnqueueAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<DateTime?>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>(), It.IsAny<double>()));
```

And this is the error message that is thrown from the verify method:

```
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.EnqueueAsync<string>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<DateTime?>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>(), It.IsAny<double>())

Performed invocations:

Mock<ITopic:1> (m):

    IServiceBus<TopicClient>.EnqueueAsync<object>(null, null, "", "c0fa2b2a-fcb7-4252-964e-cecf97bbeeb9", null, True, null, Dictionary<string, object>, 1)
```

Looking at the message comparing the definition of the verify to the invocation, I see no difference between the calls. I'm at wits end with this.

Comment: What's the type of `messageObject` that you expect? This will only match for `EnqueueAsync<string>`

Comment: It is string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `It.IsAnyType` for this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Moq;

namespace ConsoleApp24
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mock = new Mock<ITopic>();
            var ensureAsyncSetup = mock.Setup(m => m.EnqueueAsync(
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                // By using It.IsAnyType the matcher will work for all T
                It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, _) => true),
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<bool>(),
                It.IsAny<DateTime?>(),
                It.IsAny <Dictionary<string, object>>(),
                It.IsAny<double>()));

            ensureAsyncSetup.Callback((string factoryId, string clientId, object messageObject, string messageId,
                    string messageLabel, bool forcePersistence, DateTime? scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc,
                    Dictionary<string, object> properties, double retryTime) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This will run");
                });

            // Setup call as verifiable
            ensureAsyncSetup.Verifiable();

            mock.Object.EnqueueAsync(null, null, "", "c0fa2b2a-fcb7-4252-964e-cecf97bbeeb9", null, true, null, new Dictionary<string, object>(), 1);

            // This will pass as the method is called once
            mock.Verify();
        }
    }

    public interface ITopic
    {
        Task EnqueueAsync<T>(string factoryId, string clientId, T messageObject, string messageId = null, string messageLabel = null, bool forcePersistence = true, DateTime? scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = null, Dictionary<string, object> properties = null, double retryTime = 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: And Jason with the win. I knew it was something stupid!